# All GridView rows disappear while selecting a row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, selectedvalue, selectedindexchanged

Please consider the values in comments which I got in debug mode:

```
protected void FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selected = FilesGrid.SelectedIndex; // selected = 2
    FilesGrid.DataBind();  //added after feedback in comments. it makes no change
    int count = FilesGrid.Rows.Count; // count = 0
    GridViewRow row = FilesGrid.Rows[selected]; // row = null
    GridViewRow row0 = FilesGrid.Rows[0]; // row = null
}
```

I came to this code while investigating why SelectedValue gives null in this event handler (the DataKeyNames parameter was set for sure).

Can anybody explain how it is possible?

Thank you in advance.

PS.
Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="FilesGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"  
    onselectedindexchanged="FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    style="margin-top: 0px" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Length" DataFormatString="{0:N0}" 
            HeaderText="Size in Bytes" HtmlEncode="False" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is how I bind data:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string [] dd = {"FullName"};
        FilesGrid.DataKeyNames = dd;

        string appPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath; 
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(appPath); 
        FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles();
        FilesGrid.DataSource = files;
        FilesGrid.DataBind();            } 
}
```

Comment: What does gridview1.rows[index] return? Because it looks like youre pulling an items' SelectedIndex and trying to use it as the row index. My guess is you need to be finding what row the SelectedItem is in, and assigning GridViewRow row = to it.

Comment: have you tried rebinding your data to your gridview? could be losing all its items.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have just added the following: GridViewRow row0 = FilesGrid.Rows[0]; // row = null. The result is the same. Actually documentation says that GridView.SelectedIndex: Gets or sets the index of the selected row in a System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView control.

Comment: @euther: Cool advice, I have not thought about it. Unfortunately did not help.

Comment: @Kirill: you should provide more informations. Show us the GridView ASPX-markup and the codebehind where you DataBind the Grid(Page_Load?).

Comment: @Tim: Done. You're right, after commenting out the line //            if (!Page.IsPostBack) the problem seems to be resolved. So the data source is lost somehow during the postback. Which is strange because ViewState is enabled.

Comment: @Kirill: Anyway i assume that's a ViewState issue. Do you change ID's during postbacks or invalidate the ViewState(f.e. iterating the control collection in Page_PreInit)?

Comment: @Tim: No, actually that's pretty it, what the page does. I had a couple of simple event handlers more but they did nothing of the kind. And now I have commented them completely out. Anyway thank you for help. At least we made it work somehow :)

Comment: @Kirill: then i've misunderstood you somehow. The issue is solved because you are rebinding the Grid to it's DataSource on every postback in Page_Load? I would assume that this cause other problems with your events. But anyway, glad i could help.

Comment: @Tim: Of course it would be nice to know the reason of this behavior. But I hope it was just a bug and I will never run into it again. And for this simple page it is acceptable to rebind data on each postback. Thanks again.

Comment: first of all there is nothing called `FullName` inside `FileInfo` and that means your `DataKeyNames` is invalid. You may want to change it to `Name` Then on `SelectedIndexChanging` event you can get the row by `GridViewRow row = FilesGrid.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];`

Comment: @naveen: Hi thank you for your comment but I suppose it is not quite correct. You can easily see it if you instantiate FileInfo for any file and look at its properties. Furthermore FilesGrid.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex] is of no help when FilesGrid.Rows.Count gives zero as you see from my code. The whole code works if I comment out if (!Page.IsPostBack) in the Page_Load method, so it seems to be a problem with the ViewState.

Comment: @Kirill: I have added a page in a sample application and tested it. I am unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: @naveen: Thanks a lot, it makes me sure that was a local bug which I'm not going to meet ever again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by commenting out the line `// if (!Page.IsPostBack)`. It looks like the data source is lost somehow during the postback. The whole seems to be a local bug with  ViewState, because this behavior was not observed by other users. My special thanks to Tim Schmelter and naveen.

Answer (score 0):

Y copy pasted your code, delete this line  FilesGrid.DataBind() in the FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanged, i see that are 2 methods that you are not posting, that aren't in the code that you posted the onselectedindexchanging, onrowdeleting events, comment them from the aspx and see if it works, or se if that events are not doing something tricking, that are deleting the rows in your GridView.

Tell me if it works

I did this

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] dd = { "FullName" };
            FilesGrid.DataKeyNames = dd;

            string appPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(appPath);
            FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles();
            FilesGrid.DataSource = files;
            FilesGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selected = FilesGrid.SelectedIndex; // selected = 2
        //FilesGrid.DataBind();  //added after feedback in comments. it makes no change
        int count = FilesGrid.Rows.Count; // count = 0
        GridViewRow row = FilesGrid.Rows[selected]; // row = null
        GridViewRow row0 = FilesGrid.Rows[0]; // row = null
    }
    protected void FilesGrid_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The aspx code.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
            AsyncPostBackTimeout="0" EnableScriptLocalization="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>        
                <asp:GridView ID="FilesGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
                    OnRowDeleting="FilesGrid_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    Style="margin-top: 0px" OnSelectedIndexChanging="FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanging">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Length" DataFormatString="{0:N0}" HeaderText="Size in Bytes"
                            HtmlEncode="False" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>         
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Do you mean that after deleting (or adding empty in codebehind) these methods the code works on your machine? Unfortunately on mine it makes no difference. I've found out that commenting the line "if (!Page.IsPostBack)" in Page_Load helps for some reason. Anyway thank you for your effort.

Comment: i have it uncommented, and yes if you had the Postback commented, it should be the reason

Answer (score 0):

remove the `FilesGrid.DataBind();`  //added after feedback in comments. it makes no change
When I add that statement to my code I am getting the error. after removing that please try again. If not working please share the

`protected void FilesGrid_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)` method code, may be something wrong with that section

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please read comments just below the question. The issue has another nature.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `Page.IsPostBack` in `Page_Load`, I was having the same issue and it turns out the grid was not in ViewState in my case. If you use Linq query in your controller you will want to add this property to the grid so it will keep refreshing properly:
`<asp:Panel EnableViewState="True">`